# How to change default camera settings in Google Meet from 360p to 720p? (Google Workspace/G Suite)

Tags: video, video-streaming, google-meet

Every time I open a call in Google Meet, the camera settings drop down to 360p:

[image]

I have to **manually change these to 720p each time**:

[image]

How do I keep the settings at 720p permanently for all calls on my Google Meet account?

What I've tried:

- I've gone to see [the general Google Meet settings here](https://meet.google.com/), but don't have any default options there.

Click on the gear icon to see the options:

[image]

Comment: Your link appears not to go to Meet settings...

Comment: @User24601 click the gear icon

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do it at the moment

Comment: Could be an opportunity for a browser extension, if it doesn't exist yet. I.e. to support custom settings to be applied by default when Meet (or Zoom or Skype etc) gets opened in a tab.